# MVC4 publishing error - Start Page empty

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc

Just finished an MVC4 project and plubished it to a local folder.

I´ve uploaded it to my hosting but nothing happes.

Localy works fine: open the home.cshtml page, acess database, etc.

But published nothing happens.

Searching the web I´ve seen a few tutorials to how to do it. The basic dll files are in the bin folder:

```
System.Web.Mvc.dll
System.Web.Razor.dll
System.Web.Abstractions.dll
System.Web.Extensions.dll
System.Web.Http.dll
```

I did'nt change the route configuration.

Theres a default.aspx empty on the server, but none on my solution.

Do I need any other files?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed to verify in your host if they have a configuration file that could be doing this routing?

There is no tutorial on their FAQ about publishing this type of project?

Comment: Can elaborate on your answer? Please try and provide details as to how to accomplish what's your suggesting. As it stands it's difficult to follow what your saying.